# Draw intervals with overbrace descriptions

Tags: tikz-pgf

For a report I need the following picture, which I would like to draw in LaTeX/TikZ.

The idea is that there are discrete intervals on the real line and above these intervals I want to write which elements are in them...

(For example like the picture I added. )

Is there an rather easy way to draw this with `tikz`?

I never have worked with `tikz` and so maybe you can help me to draw this...

I think I will then be able to change it for other intervalls by myself.

[image]

EDIT: I found code on the internet and modified it.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=brace]
% Die Grundlinie:
\draw(0,0)--(10,0);
% Striche und Beschriftung in Abständen 0, 2, 4, 6, ...
\foreach \x/\xtext in {0/$-m-n+1$,2/$-m-1$,4/$-m$,6/$0$,8/$m$,10/$m+n-1$}
  \draw(\x,5pt)--(\x,-5pt) node[below] {\xtext};
% obere geschweifte Klammer mit Text darüber:
\draw[decorate, yshift=2ex]  (0,0) -- node[above=0.4ex] {$0$'s}  (2,0);
\draw[decorate, yshift=2ex]  (10,0) -- node[above=0.4ex] {$l$'s and $0$'s with $l$'s separated by at least two $0$'s}  (4,0);
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

What I get is:

[image]

Why is the second bracket the other way round?

Comment: you could use `\path (0,0) coordinate (a) (1,0) coordinate (b)` to establish your intervals bounds, `\draw (a) edge[|-|] (b)` to draw the intervals, `\node[anchor=south] at (a) {$-m-n+1$};` for the labels and `\draw[decoration=brace] (a) -- (b)` for the braces

Comment: Okay, pls see my edit.

Comment: it goes in the wrong direction because the path is constructed from right to left. If you swap the coordinates of the path you get it right

Comment: You can swap coordinates as Bordaigorl suggested or add `decoration=mirror` in drawing options.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The braces, from `decorations.pathreplacing` library, have an option `mirror`, which reverses the face direction of the brace. So, that is all you should add to get it in the right direction. You can do it like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% Die Grundlinie:
\draw(0,0)--(10,0);
% Striche und Beschriftung in Abständen 0, 2, 4, 6, ...
\foreach \x/\xtext in {0/$-m-n+1$,2/$-m-1$,4/$-m$,6/$0$,8/$m$,10/$m+n-1$}
    \draw(\x,5pt)--(\x,-5pt) node[below] {\xtext};
% obere geschweifte Klammer mit Text darüber:
\draw[decorate, decoration={brace}, yshift=2ex]  (0,0) -- node[above=0.4ex] {$0$'s}  (2,0);
\draw[decorate, decoration={brace, mirror}, yshift=2ex]  (10,0) -- node[above=0.4ex] {$l$'s and $0$'s with $l$'s separated by at least two $0$'s}  (4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hehe, i think thats exactly the code i found in internet, too and edited :D

Comment: @math12 So, why is it working if it is the same as yours?

Comment: Is there any way to replace braces by square brackets?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `pstricks` solution:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, pdf, x11names]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}

\begin{document}

\centering
\psset{braceWidthOuter=4pt, braceWidthInner=4pt, braceWidth=0.8pt, labelsep =2ex}
\begin{pspicture}
    \psset{linecolor =IndianRed3}
    \psline(-1.2,0)(13.2,0)
    \psdots[dotstyle=B|](0,0.02)(3,0.02)(4.2,0.02)(12,0.02)
    \pnodes(0,0.6ex){Z1}(3,0.6ex){Z2}(4.2,0.6ex){L1}(12,0.6ex){L2}
    \uput[d](Z1){$-m-n + 1$}\uput[d](Z2){$-m-1$\uput[d](L1){$-m$}}\uput[d](L2){$m + n - 1$}
    \psset{rot=-90,linecolor=SlateGray4}
    \psbrace*(Z2)(Z1){\makebox[0pt]{only $ 0 $’ s}}
    \psbrace*(L2)(L1){\makebox[0pt]{\Centerstack{$ 0 $’s and $ l $’s\\$l $’s separated by at least $ 2 $ $ 0 $’s}}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]